# Only allowing item to print if they are beside each other in nested loop

Tags: python-3.x

I am making a list where i can input items into a grid, but the input will only be accepted if it is beside each other in that list.

this is my current codes:

```
basket = [ [' ', ' ', ' ', ' '],\
            [' ', ' ', ' ', ' '],\
            [' ', ' ', ' ', ' '],\
            [' ', ' ', ' ', ' '] ]

total_moves = 1
while total_moves <= 16:
    columns = ["A", "B", "C", "D"]


    cols_string = ""
        
    for n in range(4):
        cols_string += "    {:2}".format(columns[n])

    #printing table
    print("",cols_string, end="")
        
    for idx, i in enumerate(basket):

        print('\n  ' + '+-----' * 4 + '+')
        print(idx + 1, end=" ")
        for j in i:
        
            print('|{:^5}'.format(j), end = '')

        print('|', end = '')

    print('\n  ' + '+-----' * 4 + '+')

    fruit = input('What fruit do you want to place?(APL/BNA/ORG): ')

    build_location = input('Build where? ')

            #processing build location for exact position
    build_location = list(build_location)

    if build_location[0] == 'A':
        loc = [int(build_location[1])-1, 0]

    elif build_location[0] == 'B':
        loc = [int(build_location[1])-1, 1]

    elif build_location[0] == 'C':
        loc = [int(build_location[1])-1, 2]
            
    elif build_location[0] == 'D':
        loc = [int(build_location[1])-1, 3]
    
    if build_location[1] == 'A':
        loc = [int(build_location[0])-1, 0]
                        
    elif build_location[1] == 'B':
        loc = [int(build_location[0])-1, 1]
                        
    elif build_location[1] == 'C':
        loc = [int(build_location[0])-1, 2]
            
    elif build_location[1] == 'D':
        loc = [int(build_location[0])-1, 3]

    if basket[loc[0]][loc[1]] == ' ':
        basket[loc[0]][loc[1]] = fruit

        total_moves += 1

    else:
        print('That slot is taken!')
```

This is my current print, without keying in any inputs yet:

```
     A     B     C     D 
  +-----+-----+-----+-----+
1 |     |     |     |     |
  +-----+-----+-----+-----+
2 |     |     |     |     |
  +-----+-----+-----+-----+
3 |     |     |     |     |
  +-----+-----+-----+-----+
4 |     |     |     |     |
  +-----+-----+-----+-----+
What fruit do you want to place?(APL/BNA/ORG): #input here
Build where? #input here
```

I am trying to make it such that, if I enter the fruit to be beside each other(for example`A1` and `B1`), the fruit will be printed out, but if the fruits are not beside each other(for example`A1` and `B2`), the system will print`Cannot place fruit there!`. Can anyone help me with this?

```
     A     B     C     D 
  +-----+-----+-----+-----+
1 | APL | BNA |     |     |
  +-----+-----+-----+-----+
2 |     | ORG |     |     |
  +-----+-----+-----+-----+
3 |     |     |     |     |
  +-----+-----+-----+-----+
4 |     |     |     |     |
  +-----+-----+-----+-----+
#code continues to run as the fruits are all connected to each other

     A     B     C     D 
  +-----+-----+-----+-----+
1 |     |     |     |     |
  +-----+-----+-----+-----+
2 |     | ORG | BNA |     |
  +-----+-----+-----+-----+
3 |     |     |     |     |
  +-----+-----+-----+-----+
4 |     |     |     |     |
  +-----+-----+-----+-----+

#code continues to run as fruits are connected

     A     B     C     D 
  +-----+-----+-----+-----+
1 |     |     |     |     |
  +-----+-----+-----+-----+
2 |     |     | BNA |     |
  +-----+-----+-----+-----+
3 |     | ORG |     |     |
  +-----+-----+-----+-----+
4 |     |     |     |     |
  +-----+-----+-----+-----+
#code will not run as BNA and ORG are not beside each other

     A     B     C     D 
  +-----+-----+-----+-----+
1 | APL | BNA | BNA |     |
  +-----+-----+-----+-----+
2 |     |     |     | ORG |
  +-----+-----+-----+-----+
3 |     |     |     |     |
  +-----+-----+-----+-----+
4 |     |     |     |     |
  +-----+-----+-----+-----+
#code will not run for ORG's input as ORG is not connected to the rest of the fruits, 
so system will print 'Cannot place fruit here!' and ask user to place it again, only 
continuing if ORG is at D1 or C2
```

This means for the first run, the code will accept any inputs, but for the second run onwards the code will only accept inputs which are beside the first input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code seems very neat so far and I really like your idea! Here's the implementation I came up with so far so that fruits can only be placed directly adjacent (not diagonally) to other fruits:

```
basket = [ [' ', ' ', ' ', ' '],\
        [' ', ' ', ' ', ' '],\
        [' ', ' ', ' ', ' '],\
        [' ', ' ', ' ', ' '] ]

total_moves = 1
placed = [] #new

def valid(build_location, placed): #new
  for loc in placed:
    if abs(ord(loc[0]) - ord(build_location[0])) == 1 and loc[1] == build_location[1]:
      return True
    if abs(ord(loc[1]) - ord(build_location[1])) == 1 and loc[0] == build_location[0]:
      return True
  if len(placed) == 0:
    return True
  return False
while total_moves <= 16:
    columns = ["A", "B", "C", "D"]


    cols_string = ""
    
    for n in range(4):
        cols_string += "    {:2}".format(columns[n])

    #printing table
    print("",cols_string, end="")
    
    for idx, i in enumerate(basket):

        print('\n  ' + '+-----' * 4 + '+')
        print(idx + 1, end=" ")
        for j in i:
    
            print('|{:^5}'.format(j), end = '')

        print('|', end = '')

    print('\n  ' + '+-----' * 4 + '+')

    fruit = input('What fruit do you want to place?(APL/BNA/ORG): ')

    build_location = input('Build where? ')

            #processing build location for exact position
    build_location = list(build_location)
    if valid(build_location, placed): #new
      placed.append(build_location)
      if build_location[0] == 'A':
          loc = [int(build_location[1])-1, 0]

      elif build_location[0] == 'B':
          loc = [int(build_location[1])-1, 1]

      elif build_location[0] == 'C':
          loc = [int(build_location[1])-1, 2]
          
      elif build_location[0] == 'D':
          loc = [int(build_location[1])-1, 3]
      
      if build_location[1] == 'A':
        loc = [int(build_location[0])-1, 0]
                    
      elif build_location[1] == 'B':
          loc = [int(build_location[0])-1, 1]
                      
      elif build_location[1] == 'C':
          loc = [int(build_location[0])-1, 2]
          
      elif build_location[1] == 'D':
          loc = [int(build_location[0])-1, 3]
  
      if basket[loc[0]][loc[1]] == ' ':
        basket[loc[0]][loc[1]] = fruit
        total_moves += 1
      else: #new
        print('That spot is taken!')

    else: #new
        print('Can not place fruit there!')
```

Let me explain the code now:

First, I created an array to store the positions of fruit that have already been placed. For simplicity, I altered the code so that it would only accept positions that are placed like (A1, B2, C2, D4) and not (1A, 2B, 2C, 4D).

Next, I created a function that verifies whether or not the position is valid. This is done by looping through the array and comparing it to other fruits. If the difference in letters is 1 AND the numbers are the same, it is valid. If the difference in numbers is 1 AND the letters are the same, it is valid.

Additionally, there is an if statement at the bottom of the code that makes sure it does not overlap another fruit and gives a separate error message.

Let me know if you have any other questions!

Comment: Hi Aniketh, thank you so much for the answer! I am aware you took out the inputs for positions that are like 1A, 2B etc, but is it possible to implement that into the code as well?

Comment: Sure, give me a few minutes

Comment: The code should be edited now to support 1A/A1